# MVC Controller different parameter signature for method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

- MVC 5, .NET 4.5.1

In my base Controller class I have the following defined

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public virtual ActionResult Edit(long Id)
    {
    }
```

This has been fine up to now. However in the new controller class which descends from above I need to change the method signature to:

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public new ActionResult Edit(string Id)
    {
    }
```

Note that the parameter Id is now a **string**. However when the action is invoked on the descendant controller I get the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int64)' in 'XXXX.Controllers.MlControllerGridView`2[MakersLane.Web.ViewModels.Login.LoginAddEditViewModel,XXXX.Web.ViewModels.Login.LoginAddEditViewModel]'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

So my question is how do I change the parameter Id to be of type **string** in my descendant controller and not access any base behaviour?

Comment: Why do you have that method in the base class to begin with?

Comment: Its historical and I cannot change it right at the minute. So I need to work around the issue

Comment: Just make a new method and add a new route.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by doing the using the [NonAction] attribute. This way the "long id" is "removed" and it correctly picks up the "string id" version. Not pretty, but it works.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(string Id)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("NotYetImplemented", "SystemManagement");
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     To work around the base class requiredment that the Id be a long we override the
    ///     base class and mark this as not an action. Use the string version instead.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [NonAction]
    public override ActionResult Edit(long Id)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("NotYetImplemented", "SystemManagement");
    }
```